# How can I pass simulationClass as a parmeter in gatling

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

please I have several simulation Classes and I want to give the users possibility to enter the name of simulation he / she wants to run from a jenkins pipline
For that I want to parametrize the simulation name so insted that user write the command : mvn gatling -Dgatling.simulationClass=package.theNameofSimulation ( here the name is static)  , I want him directy enter the name of simulation he choose, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQTXq.png)
because I guess that the user doesn't know the code and commands

so we have the possibility to passing in parameter the numberOfVirtuelUsers I want to do the same thing for simulation

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you create an environment variable, you could paramatize the simulation classes. I'm very note sure because i'm newbie in gatling but i do that on other things like URL, users, time etc... and that's work so why not the simulation class.

String nameSimulation = String.format("Dgatling.simulationClass=package.%s", System.getenv("NAME"));